# Retrieving all the documents from CloudFirestore and display in a "Fragment" which contains a recycler view

Tags: java, android

*This is the Fragment*

```
package com.example.sabih.startup;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentChange;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.EventListener;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestoreException;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class GlobalFragment extends Fragment {

public RecyclerView globalRecycler;
public List<ideas> globalList;
public FirebaseFirestore firestore;
public globalAdapter adapter;
public GlobalFragment(){

}
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.globalfragment, container, false);
    globalRecycler = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.globalRecyclerView);
    globalList = new ArrayList<ideas>();
    adapter = new globalAdapter(globalList);
    globalRecycler.setHasFixedSize(true);
    globalRecycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    globalRecycler.setAdapter(adapter);
    firestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    firestore.collection("UserIdeaOrDescription").addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(QuerySnapshot documentSnapshots, FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
            for (DocumentChange doc:documentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges())
            {
                if (doc.getType() == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED)
                {
                    ideas newIdeas = doc.getDocument().toObject(ideas.class);
                    globalList.add(newIdeas);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        }
    });
    return view;
}
}
```

*This is the adapter*

```
package com.example.sabih.startup;

import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

public class globalAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<globalAdapter.ViewHolder> {

public List<ideas> GlobalList;

public globalAdapter(List<ideas> GlobalList) {
    this.GlobalList = GlobalList;
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView mTitle;
    View mView;
    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mView = itemView;
    }
    public void setContents(String titles)
    {
        mTitle = mView.findViewById(R.id.titleIdeaText);
        mTitle.setText(titles);
    }
}
@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.ideaslayout,parent,false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    String title_data = GlobalList.get(position).getTitle();
    holder.setContents(title_data);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return GlobalList.size();
}
}
```

I just wanted to display "Titles" out of all the fields...
I have 4 fields in the document section of the firestore - Description, Tag, Title and user_id.
When I try to run it using only Activity it works but when I do it inside a fragment The screen displays a blank recycler view.. even after adding the fields into the firestore.

Answer (score 0):

Try to fetch data and set in onViewCreated()

```
    @Override
        public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

 globalRecycler = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.globalRecyclerView);
    globalList = new ArrayList<ideas>();
    adapter = new globalAdapter(globalList);
    globalRecycler.setHasFixedSize(true);
    globalRecycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    globalRecycler.setAdapter(adapter);
    firestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    firestore.collection("UserIdeaOrDescription").addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(QuerySnapshot documentSnapshots, FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
            for (DocumentChange doc:documentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges())
            {
                if (doc.getType() == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED)
                {
                    ideas newIdeas = doc.getDocument().toObject(ideas.class);
                    globalList.add(newIdeas);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: No..no errors..it's running smoothly..all other functions are being  performed perfectly..just the fragment part is blank..